# Java Convert ß, ä, ö and other special characzers to Ascii

Tags: java, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I want to convert some special characters like "ß" in Java to an ASCII code.
I tried it with

```
String abc = "ß";
byte[] bytes = abc.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

which resulted in 63 (aswell as ä, ö,...).

I also tried

```
String abc = "ß";
byte[] bytes = abc.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

which resulted in -61 and -97 (seems like doing so with ä, ö,... it starts always with -61, followed by another negative number).

I have another programm, that seems to do it right, and converts ß to 195 and 159 (ä, ö,... start with 195 too, followed by another number).

How can I convert these characters properly, so that I get the result with 195 and the other number?

Comment: Java bytes are signed, which means they run from -128 to 127. -61 is the signed equivalent of 195.

Comment: Did you notice that 195 = -61 + 256? Java bytes are signed so they are in the [-128, 127] interval. What you want is the UTF-8 encoding in the range [0, 255], so you should use `byte[] bytes = abc.getBytes("UTF-8");` and **in an integer array** add 256 to negative numbers.

Comment: Oh yes, okay Thank you @SergeBallesta